# Get a file URL from a custom entity referenced on a user profile

Tags: entities

I have an entity called CV which is used to store uploaded CVs. The entity is created and referenced on the user profile using inline entity form. I need to get the fid for the cv so I can do this:

```
$uri = file_load($fid)->uri;
$file_name = file_load($fid)->filename;
$path = file_create_url($uri);
```

I've tried to use entity_metadata_wrapper, but I'm not sure how to actually access the correct field. This is an example of what I've been trying:

```
$wrapper = entity_metadata_wrapper('candidate_cv', $cv);
$cv_file = $wrapper->field_candidate_cv->value();
```

Which returns this error:

```
EntityMetadataWrapperException: Unknown data property field_candidate_cv.
```

Update:
I have managed to get the title of the entity using this:

```
$cv_wrapper = entity_metadata_wrapper('user', $user);
$cv_upload = array();
foreach ($cv_wrapper->field_cv->value() as $index => $feature) {
    $cv_upload[] = $feature->title;
}
echo title[0];
```

But I can't get to the fid of the file field which is field_candidate_cv.

```
$cv_wrapper = entity_metadata_wrapper('user', $user);
   $cv_upload = array();
   foreach ($cv_wrapper->field_cv->value() as $index => $feature) {
        $cv_upload[] = $feature->field_candidate_cv;
    }
    $fid = $cv_upload[0]['fid'];
```

$fid prints nothing.

However, in this $fid prints Array:

```
 $fid = $cv_upload[0];
```

Comment: It seems that your entity is not properly defined or that entiy has no field called field_candidate_cv

Comment: It definitely has that field, so how do I properly define the entity?

Comment: try to access the property without metadata wrapper en check if that approach works

Comment: I tried accessing the field with metadata wrapper but it returned this: 'Warning: array_flip(): Can only flip STRING and INTEGER values! in EntityCacheControllerHelper::entityCacheLoad()'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution:

```
$cv_wrapper = entity_metadata_wrapper('user', $user);
$cv_upload = array();
foreach ($cv_wrapper->field_cv->value() as $feature) {
    $cv_upload[] = $feature->field_candidate_cv;
}
$fid = $cv_upload[0]['und'][0]['fid'];
```

Printed the array of $cv_upload using:

```
drupal_set_message('<pre>'. print_r($cv_upload, TRUE) .'</pre>');
```